# Remove original image after automatic creation of featured image

Tags: image, wordpress, posting

I installed the plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-featured-image-posts/ but I am having a problemm, because the plugin doesn't remove the original image from the post content after creating the featured image. (and therefore when I don't add the featured image there appear 2 images on the post) 
I tried adding this to the auto-featured-image.php

> add_action('publish_post', 'eliminaroriginal');

and then

> function eliminaroriginal(){      //update the post without image
>         $post_parent_id = $post->post_parent === 0 ? $post->ID :
>   $post->post_parent;       $contenido = preg_replace("/[caption
>   .+?[/caption]|\< *[img][^>]*[.]*>/i", "", $post->post_content,
>   1);       $mipost = array();      $mipost['ID'] = $post_parent_id; 
>         $mipost['post_content'] = $contenido;       wp_update_post( $mipost );
>         }

but it didn't have any result.
Please help me, I don't know what should I do.

Thank you before hand!